# Rows in a table that have no counterpart in another two tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT left_tbl.*
  FROM left_tbl LEFT JOIN right_tbl ON left_tbl.id = right_tbl.id
  WHERE right_tbl.id IS NULL;
```

The code above works beautifully when you are searching rows from left table without a counterpart in one right table.

But how do I find rows from left table without a counterpart in two right tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find records in `LEFT_TBL` that doesn't exist in both of the two other tables?  The most readable would be:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM LEFT_TBL lt
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM TABLE_A a
                   WHERE a.id = lt.id)
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM TABLE_B b
                   WHERE b.id = lt.id)
```

Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT lt.*
     FROM LEFT_TBL lt
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a ON a.id = lt.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.id = lt.id
    WHERE a.id IS NULL
      AND b.id IS NULL
```

If you want `LEFT_TBL` records that do not exist in one of the two tables, change the `AND` in the `WHERE` clause to `OR`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is what i was looking for. 
I test it both and both work. 
For some reason when i used "LEFT_TBL lt ... lt.id" did not worked but when i used "LEFT_TBL ... LEFT_TBL.id" it did work. I also tried with "LEFT_TBL AS lt" with no succes. Maybe it's because of the way my code is structured.